# Can't display and concatenate variables with JQuery in CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I have many of CKEditor element on my web page, and all of them have the same ID syntax like id='tacontributionn' :

```html
<div id="contributions">
  
<textarea id='tacontribution1' required autofocus  ></textarea>  
<textarea id='tacontribution2' required autofocus  ></textarea>  
<textarea id='tacontribution3' required autofocus  ></textarea>
  
                          ...
  
<textarea id='tacontributionn' required autofocus  ></textarea>
  
<input class="btnn-contribution btn btn-primary col-md-2"  type="submit"/>
```

I want to to retrieve some of them with ajax at a very specific time inside my ajax.js file.

I did as follow :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-contribution').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
      
        var number = $(this).parent().data('number')
        
        var ckID = 'tacontribution'+number;
        

        var ckContent = CKEDITOR.instances.ckID.getData();
        
        alert(ckContent); //Just to test, but it doesn't work
      
      //blah blah blah


    })


})
```

But it seems I can't concatenate 2 variables and put it in CKEDITOR.instances.there.getData()

Please How can I deal with that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem.
Instead of var ckContent = CKEDITOR.instances.ckID.getData(), I used var ckContent = CKEDITOR.instances[ckID].getData(), and it works insanely great.

So we have :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.btn-contribution').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
      
        var number = $(this).parent().data('number')
        
        var ckID = 'tacontribution'+number;
        

        var ckContent = CKEDITOR.instances[ckID].getData();
        
        alert(ckContent); //It works now


    })


})
```